# Can I ask Nancy if a view exists?

Tags: nancy

In my nancy project I have views which are based on a 4-digit numeric id, as in 1234.cshtml, 2345.cshtml et cetera.  Not all 10000 values exist, and if an id is requested for which there is not a view, I want to redirect to another page.

In my routing code how can I test if, for example, view 5432.cshtml exists?  is there a helper method in Nancy for this?  Or should I just query the file system?

Answer (score 0):

inject `IViewLocator` and use `LocateView` method to test if the view exists.